# EFCodeFirst - Initialize DB and create tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Is there a way to create the tables through a SQL script when the database is initialized in EFCodeFirst approach. ( I mean, to avoid auto table creation and use my custom script instaead for table creation).

I've tried below approach, but it doesn't seem to be creating the table as per the SQL script. **context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand** is supposed to work for DDL SQL as well as DML SQL.

```
class Class1
{

    public void InitializeDB()
    {
        Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");

        var dbInitializer = new DbInitializer();
        Database.SetInitializer(dbInitializer);
        var target = new MyDbContext();
        target.Database.Initialize(true);
    }
}

public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    private string CreateTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogins](" +
                         "[UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," +
                         "[UserName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL," +
                         "[FirstName] [nvarchar](200) NULL," +
                         "[LastName] [nvarchar](200) NULL )";

    public void InitializeDatabase(MyDbContext context)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(CreateTableSQL, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inherit `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` you cannot change `InitializeDatabase` logic because that method is not `virtual`. Instead of inheriting `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` implement `IDatabaseInitializer` directly.